# .NET query getting inappropriate answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I was at career fair and I was asked a question "what does this query do and in which language it is".

I told that it is in .NET LINQ, but was unable to predict what it does.

Can any one help me

I wrote in .NET and tried .

```
 var youShould = from c
  in "3%.$@9/52@2%35-%@4/@./3,!#+%23 !2#526%N#/-"
                        select (char)(c ^ 3 << 5);

        Label1.Text = youShould.ToString();
```

And got this output :

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.Char]
```

Comment: Frankly, if they think that this is a valid test of ability, they're having a laugh. Do you really want to work for these guys?

Comment: My answer would be ".net Linq, and what it does is confuse the hell out of me and if any one on my team wrote this without meaningful comment would be buying the rest of the team a case of beer. Each. BUt yeah there is something to do with BitShifting in there"

Comment: The truth is that it doesn't do anything until you consume the `IEnumerable`... But I doubt that's what they were looking for. Maybe that's what you were looking for? Consuming it and maybe making it into a string?

Comment: @spender I think it is ok test to quickly weed out people who don't know difference between framework and language... It was "career fair" not 8 hours interview...

Comment: Well, LINQ is not a language; that code is clearly C# so they didn't even get that part right. And that's a terrible way to "weed out" good developers, as all it will tell you is if they can do bit math and know the ASCII table by heart, neither of which has much to do with real world programming skill.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, don't feel bad that you didn't get the answer. I know exactly what's going on here and I'd have probably just laughed and walked away if someone asked me what this did.

There's a number of things going on here, but start with the output:

```
var youShould = from c in "3%.$@9/52@2%35-%@4/@./3,!#+%23 !2#526%N#/-"
                select (char)(c ^ 3 << 5);
Label1.Text = youShould.ToString();

>>> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.Char]
```

When you run a LINQ query, or use any of the equivalent methods like `Select()` that return sets, what you get back is a special, internal type of object called an "iterator", specifically, an object that implements the `IEnumerable` interface. .NET uses these objects all over the place; for example, the `foreach` loop's purpose is to iterate over iterators.

One of the most important things to know about these kind of objects is that just creating one doesn't actually "do" anything. The iterator doesn't actually contain a set of things; rather, it contains the instructions needed to *produce* a set of things. If you try to do something like, e.g. `ToString` on it, the result you get won't be very useful.

However, it does tell us one thing: it tells us that this particular iterator takes a source list of type `char` and returns a new set, also of type `char`. (I know that because I know that's what the two generic parameters of a "select iterator" do.) To get the actual results out of this iterator you just need to loop over it somehow, e.g.:

```
foreach (var c in youShould)
{
    myLabel.Text += c;
}
```

or, slightly easier,

```
myLabel.Text = new string(youShould.ToArray());
```

To actually figure out what it does, you have to also recognize the second fact: LINQ treats a string as a "set of characters". It is going to process each character in that string, one at a time, and perform the bit-wise operations on the value.

The long-form equivalent of that query is something like this:

```
var input= "3%.$@9/52@2%35-%@4/@./3,!#+%23 !2#526%N#/-";
var output = string.Empty;
foreach (var c in input)
{
   var i = (int)c;
   var i2 = i ^ (3 << 5);

   var c2= (char)i2;

   output += c2;
}
```

If you did the math by hand you'd get the correct output message. To save you the brain-numbing exercise, I'll just tell you: it toggles bits 5 and 6 of the ASCII value, changing each character to one further up the ASCII table. The resulting string is:

> SEND YOUR RESUME TO [an email address]

Demostrative .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x7UvYA

Comment: I'd upvote gain if I could just for indroducing me to dotnetfiddle

Comment: I love how their stunt has backfired and made a bunch of SOer stay away from their company.

Comment: meh. in retrospect, the purpose of their stunt may actually have been to get you to go home and run the code for yourself, and not actually sit there at the job fair and figure it out. Not being there I've decided it's probably not fair to mock them without knowing more.

Answer (score 2):

For each character in the string, project the character by xor-ing it with (3 left shifted by 5), then cast the numeric value back to a char.

You could generate your own code strings by running the query again over an uncoded string, because if you XOR a number twice by the same value, you'll be left with the same number you started with. (e.g. `x ^ y ^ y = x`)

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out what the following is:

```
4()3@)3@!@$5-"@4%34
```

I suppose it tests:

- Linq to objects
- Understanding of `IEnumerable<T>` interface and how it relates to strings
- Casting
- Bitwise operations
- Bitwise operator precedence

Personally, I think this is a useless test that doesn't really reflect real world problems.